# i have menu with submenu ;when i click on menu it should not open because it has submenu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

my question is

i have menu with submenu ;when i click on menu it should not open because it has submenu ; in wordpress

see ex

> Blockquote

https://wordpress.org/support/ ; when i click on support it open ,but it have two sub menu forums & Documentation;
My simple question is when i click on menu it should not happen because it has two sub menu ,it should open on clicking on submenu

Comment: I believe you have missed your sample

Answer (score 0):

- Under `wp-admin/Appearance/Menus` click `Custom Links` (on the left hand side)
- Leave the `URL` field blank
- In the `Link Text` field, enter whatever text you wish to show as the main item on the menu
- Next, add your sub-menu items (Posts/Pages) to the menu and drag them indented under the main item

This way, the main item on the menu won't be clickable, but a sub-menu would show up, with clickable links.